# Android Services Problem?

Tags: android, service

I've a application where a service is running in background and when a Serial port is connected this service will tell the activity that serial port is connected.    Now ,If service is inactive or it is killed by Android for space allocation and some data comes from UART , who will serve this data?

Please answer urgently. Thank you.

Comment: Android does not have UART/serial support AFAIK. It is impossible to say, for some modified firmware, what is supposed to happen. You need to ask whoever modified the firmware what is supposed to happen.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a small native program and modify the init.rc to mark it to be restarted in case it dies..